# I can not call java from php

Tags: java, php, windows-server-2012

The system variable 'Path' contains `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\`
It seems like, I cant even access java from PHP. The system is Windows Server 2012. From the cmd terminal, java works fine.

When I call the java command via `exec` from php like this:

```
exec("java -version", $string);
preg_match("/java version \"(.*)\..*.*\"/", $string[0], $matches);
$java_version = $matches[1];
```

`$java_version` is null.

Any ideas?

---

I suspect, it has something to do with access rights on Windows, might that be?

Comment: First of all you should check if you get anything here `$string[0]`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw an identical question yesterday...

Comment: no, nothing in $string[0]

Comment: yes, I posted yesterday a similar question but tagged it wrongly, so it was mostly overseen.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `java -version` the output is written to `stderr`. So write

```
exec("java -version 2>&1", $string);
```

to capture `stderr` output.

Comment: @Ferenjito then use the full path